# Eloquent where clause in JOIN table - Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two models which are connected each other.

```
class Company extends Model {
   public function addresses() {
      return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Address', 'address_mapping', 'uid_company', 'uid_address');
   }
}

class Address extends Model {
}
```

In my JOIN table I have a column named active. How can I fetch all active addresses from the company? Or how can I implement a where-clause in the JOIN table?

Thank you!

Comment: This should answer your question: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Yes, right. I didn't know the term pivot table. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table that you call a "JOIN table", usually called a *pivot table*.
You can fetch all active records by using `wherePivot` method:

```
 $company = Company::first();   
 $activeAdresses = $company->addresses()->wherePivot('active', 1);
```

Or you can directly define the relationship in your model:

```
class Company extends Model {
   public function activeAddresses() {
      return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Address', 'address_mapping', 'uid_company', 'uid_address')
                  ->wherePivot('active', 1);
   }
}
```

See section *Filtering Relationships Via Intermediate Table Columns* in [Eloquent documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: Or directly define in model like [Filtering Relationships Via Intermediate Table Columns](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)